# How can I debug internet server on Windows VirtualBox using NAT and port forwarding?

Tags: networking, router, nat, virtualbox, port-forwarding

I am using a program called Memoq that listens on port 2705. I would like to make it accessible from the internet, but it is failing for unknown reasons.

The setup looks like this:
Internet -> Router -> Server -> Virtualbox computer with Memoq

I set the router to forward port 2705 to the server and Virtualbox to forward port 2705 from host to guest (using NAT). I disabled firewall on both computers (they run Windows).

If I try to telnet to port 2705 from virtualbox and server it works, but if i do the same from some other computer (internet or network) it fails.

I'm not a network expert, how could I find out what is wrong?

Comment: Virtualbox is not a reasonable hypervisor technology to be using as an IT professional.  Put a real hypervisor on your server.

Comment: I don't really need professional level of service. Quick, dirty & free is good enough in this specific case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is most likely that you're double-NAT'ing the traffic via both your router and the host server.

I would personally move the VM to use bridged networking, and then port-forward straight to the VM from your router.

---

I also agree wth HopelessN00b's comment that you should be replacing VirtualBox with a decent hypervisor, such as HyperV on Windows.

Comment: Thanks, bridged connection really helped. I solved the problem with your help.